# Extracting values from a string using grep and awk

Tags: grep

I have the following string,

> Name>Brazin>td>41.158>/td>>td>123>/td>>tdclass="Something">252>/td>

for which I am trying to extract values where the output should be
Brazin: 41.158, 123

How can I get the output using grep and awk.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `awk`:

```
echo "Name>Brazin>td>41.158>/td>ng">252>/td>" | awk -F">" '{ printf "%s: %s, %s", $2,$4,$8 }'
```

Result:

```
Brazin: 41.158, 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need grep or awk, just sed.  Try this:

```
echo "Name>Brazin>td>41.158>/td>>td>123>/td>>tdclass="Something">252>/td>" |
    sed 's/Name>\([^>]*\)>td>\([^>]*\)>\/td>>td>\([^>]*\).*/\1: \2, \3/'
```